# gnome-shell.css does not exist

Tags: gnome, icons, unity-dash

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1 and want to resize the icons in the dash. Therefore I wanted to edit the file /usr/share/gnome-shell/themes/gnome-shell.css

This file does not exist, but rather the file "gnome-shell.css.save", which I can't open. Any ideas?

And is this even the right file to change the icon size? I am not talking about the desktop icons, but the icons the the dash.

I know there have been lots of similar questions, but I googled all night and couldnt find the right answer.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a copy of the default shell css here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/master/data/theme/gnome-shell.css

You can indeed use this as a base to override the default shell styling like increasing the font size.

Get the User Theme extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

Create a directory:
`mkdir $HOME/.themes/new-theme-name/gnome-shell`

Copy that Gnome basefile to it:

```
cd $HOME/.themes/new-theme-name/gnome-shell
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/master/data/theme/gnome-shell.css
```

Append the very end of the file with your desired "overrides".
Example:

```
/* Increase font size here */
stage {
    font-family: cantarell, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: white;
}
```

Using the **tweak-tool** switch to your new theme.

I realize the OP asked about icons, but this should be a similar process.